# c:out is not giving output in jsp Files

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss

I am using c:out in jsp file for avoiding cross site scripting issues. But I'm not getting expected output. I tried some of the existing stackoverflow references but to no avail. 
I have already used the following line of code in my JSP files :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

but the code doesn't give any output. Here is a code snippet exemplifying my concern

```
<td class="body"><a href="........?action=a&b=<c:out value="${id}" />"><c:out value="${name}" /> </a> </td>
```

Within the above snippet, c:out doesn't output anything for me and instead provides the following output:

[image]

Image showing tabular output with nothing being shown in cell under the name column

Can anyone suggest a better XSS compliant JSTL Library in place of c:out that I can use? Of course, I would also prefer any correction to the code snippet provided in this post.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You haven't posted any code, nor any output. So we can't debug it.

Comment: Again, post the actual output you get, and all the relevant code. We have no idea of where `id` and `name` come from.

Comment: I have posted an image

Comment: So you're using Tomcat and JSTL is not correctly installed? Please exactly specify which server you're using and how exactly you installed and configured JSTL. Please also tell what exactly you're seeing in generated HTML source. Are the JSTL tags still there or are they correctly stripped out? *"Can anyone suggest a better XSS compliant JSTL Library in place of c:out that I can use?"* Frankly, this statement makes no utter sense.